# How to migrate map from tile size 256 to 512 in d3-geo-tile and ArcGIS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, arcgis

We have a developed a map using d3-map-tile and using [ArcGIS](https://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer) services which is having tile-size 256X256. We were able to render our map and plot the latitude longitude properly.

Now we have to move to the [service](https://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D/MapServer) where tile size is 512X512. Rendering of lat-long is not working properly by just merely changing the services.

Can someone tell me how I can do it in my existing code. what are the things I need to change apart from services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking (as of August 2017), no. The size is fixed within the tile module:

> Computes the set of 256x256 quadtree tiles to display given the
>   current layout extent, scale and translate. ([API docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-tile#_tile))

And Mike states:

> It currently is limited to 256 [px] ([discussion](https://github.com/d3/d3-tile/issues/22))

However, as coincidence has it, work is occurring to address multiple tile sizes.

See the discussion [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-tile/issues/22). In fact, it seems that a possible implementation has been developed, see this [thread](https://github.com/d3/d3-tile/pull/35), and this [block](http://bl.ocks.org/linusmarco/71f80d7c8a53981f5bbfab8167f32a10) for an example using the possible implementation.